# Mvc returning null value back from view for list<> object in model

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

In an mvc 3 .Net FW 4.0 project I have a data that relates in a parent child relationship, I've built up my model to contain a list of "children" with each parent record, and displaying it as in the following example:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/ViewMasterPage.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcTest.Models.ModelList>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    ShowPropReturn
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>ShowPropReturn</h2>

<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>ModelList</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyProperty1) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyProperty1) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyProperty1) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyProperty2) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyProperty2) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyProperty2) %>
        </div>

        <table>
        <% foreach (var item in Model.MyProperty3)
           { %>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(i => item.string1) %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(i => item.string2) %>
                    </td>
                </tr>

        <% } %>
        </table>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
<% } %>

<div>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
</div>

</asp:Content>
```

I figured out that if a displayfor is used to only display a field value, it does not get posted back which makes sense. But I'm getting a null for the child list object in the model on httppost and I need to have these items edited on the same view, it is also null in the formcollection object, can anyone help me on this please?

Comment: See [Darin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895793/mvc-returning-null-value-back-from-view-for-list-object-in-model/5895839#5895839) for the solution. But why isn't your approach working? The lambda passed to `EditorFor` needs to select a property or field of the *model type* of the page/control. It will not be passed some other thing in scope: `item` is never passed, so how can it be used inside the implementation of `EditorFor`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the `foreach` loop try using an editor template:

```
<table>
    <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.MyProperty3)
</table>
```

and inside the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/SomeModelType.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<AppName.SomeModelType>" 
%>
<tr>
    <td>
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.string1) %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.string2) %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now this will generate proper input field names so that when you submit the form values will be correctly bound.

Remark: In this case I assume that `MyProperty3` on your main view model is defined like this (a collection of `SomeModelType`):

```
public IEnumerable<SomeModelType> MyProperty3 { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Erika - I was able to make that work by using for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.MyList.Count(); i++) {
    @Html.TextboxFor(m => m.MyList[i].someproperty)
}
```

However, I like Darin's solution better.

Also I discovered that binding will not work if you set the Name property of a helper

Answer (score 1):

Darin's answer is correct, but there is a caveat:  you need to have a field in your form for each "set" field in the model, otherwise it isn't a match and the resulting List of model is null.

Consider this case for a List of AccountModel:

```
public class AccountModel
{
    public AccountType Type { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public string Name { get { return Util.GetAccountTypeName(Type); } }
}
```

The parent view need only contain ...

```
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Accounts)
```

... where ...

```
    List<AccountModel> Accounts { get; set; }
```

... is part of your overall ViewModel.

Now, if you create your editor template like this ...

```
@model WebLinx.Models.AccountModel

    <div class="informationRow">        
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Selected) 
        <div class="formLabel">
            @Html.Label(Model.Name)
        </div>
    </div>
```

... then you will get a null object back in your parent model when you submit, even though the list of accounts with checkboxes view appears complete when displayed.

But if you include one extra line:

```
@model WebLinx.Models.AccountModel

    <div class="informationRow">        
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Selected) 
        @Html.HiddenFor( x=> x.Type)  @* extra line with hidden field *@
        <div class="formLabel">
        @Html.Label(Model.Name)
        </div>
    </div>
```

then you have a complete match between the form and the AccountModel object, and the List of AccountModel will contain all the members (and updated values for the checkboxes).

Comment: Great explanation. Adding all the fields this way helped me solve the problem.